# Is it possible to host Java Spring application over Firebase hosting?

Tags: java, spring, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am seeking information about using Firebase (as database) for Java. Is this possible along with hosting of Java (using Spring framework) project over Firebase hosting.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible. Use Google App Engine an environment for running application code in the cloud; Platform as a service (PaaS).

Below is description how make to make basic example.

In the this tutorial, you'll learn how to:
Create a backend service running on App Engine using Android Studio.
Connect the backend service to your data in Firebase.

The sample app stores a to-do list in Firebase, which automatically synchronizes the data across devices, and then uses backend logic running on App Engine to send out daily reminder emails:

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio

By connecting App Engine to a Firebase database, you can perform complex logic on data without having to manage synchronization and updates; Firebase handles that for you.

Answer (score 2):

No. Firebase offers hosting for static assets only.

Comment: What about hosting Firebase(database) and Java - Spring (backend) hosting over Google App Engine ..?

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/) seems is most suitable for what you want.

Consider to check the documentation and pricing. Like firebase, cloud run also has a free tier that can help you develop your app with no costs.

The cloud run supports several programming languages including Java.
Once created the service you can try to connect to your firebase project...

[Cloud Run Java Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-java-service)